# Server-side function is called only once in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-formatter

I've put a jqgrid the page. In Jqgrid placed  a column that I want when user click on the column, Fill Other Jqgrid.Now when I click on the desired column. Only first-time Fill second JQGrid,But the next time the server side code will not run.
The code is written as follows

```
var firstButtonColumnIndex = 0;
            grid = $('#list'); buttonNames = {};
            grid.jqGrid({
                url: 'jQGridHandler.ashx?Request=1',
                loadonce: true,
                direction: "rtl",
                pgtext: "صفحه {0} از {1}",
                datatype: 'json',
                height: 250,
                colNames: ['شماره درخواست', 'شماره اموال', 'شرح دستور کار', 'تاریخ دستور کار', 'زمان دستور کار', 'ملاحظات', '', ''],
                colModel: [

                        { name: 'WorkOrderNo', width: 100, sortable: true },
                        { name: 'AssetNo', width: 100, sortable: true },
                        { name: 'WorkDescription', width: 400, sortable: true },
                        { name: 'WorkOrderDate', width: 80, sortable: true },
                        { name: 'WorkOrderTime', width: 80, sortable: true },
                        { name: 'Remark', width: 100, sortable: true },
                        { name: 'del', width: 20, sortable: false, search: false,
                            formatter: function () {
                                return "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-trash'></span>";
                            }
                        },
                        { name: 'details', width: 20, sortable: false, search: false,
                            formatter: function () {
                                return "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-document'></span>";
                            }
                        }

                    ],
                gridview: true,
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                pager: '#pager',
                //  sortname: 'WorkOrderNo',
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: 'asc',
                caption: 'درخواست ها...........',
                rownumbers: true,
                beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
                    var iCol = $.jgrid.getCellIndex(e.target);
                    if (iCol == 7) {
                        //alert("rowid=" + rowid + "\nButton name: " + buttonNames[iCol]);
                        // $('img').each(function () {
                        $("#workRequestPopUp").draggable();
                        //  });

                    } else if (iCol == 8) {
                        workOrderId = rowid;

                        $("#tblRequestWorks tr").remove();
                        $("#tblRequestWorks").jqGrid({
                           // url: 'jQGridHandler.ashx?RequestWorksFill=1&workOrderId=' + workOrderId,
                            url: "PublicHandler.ashx?Request=1&workOrderId: rowid",
                            direction: "rtl",
                            pgtext: "",
                            datatype: 'json',
                            height: 250,
                            colNames: ['نام کار', 'نام واحد', 'سرپرست واحد', 'تعداد', 'پایان کار', ''],
                            colModel: [

                        { name: 'WorkName', width: 300, sortable: true },
                        { name: 'SectionName', width: 100, sortable: true },
                        { name: 'SectionSupervisor', width: 100, sortable: true },
                        { name: 'RequestCount', width: 80, sortable: true },
                        { name: 'FinishWork', width: 100, sortable: true },
                        { name: 'details', width: 20, sortable: false, search: false,
                            formatter: function () {
                                return "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-document'></span>";
                            }
                        }

                    ],

                            rowNum: 10,
                            rowList: [10, 20, 30],

                            sortorder: 'asc',
                            caption: 'Test',
                            rownumbers: true,
                            beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
                                var iCol = $.jgrid.getCellIndex(e.target);
                                if (iCol == 6) {
                                    alert(rowid);
                                    Fill12(rowid);
                                } else if (iCol == 8) {
                                    alert(rowid);
                                    Fill12(rowid);

                                    return true;

                                    // return (iCol >= firstButtonColumnIndex) ? false : true;

                                }
                            },
                            dataType: "json"

                        });
                        //  fillRequestWorkPopup(workOrderId);

                        popup(e);
                    }
                    // prevent row selection if one click on the button
                    // return (iCol >= firstButtonColumnIndex) ? false : true;
                    return true;
                }


            });
```

It is Delegate Function in tr in JQGrid?
I respected professors can help. thanks All

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL `"PublicHandler.ashx?Request=1&workOrderId: rowid"` seems me wrong. Do you mean probably `"PublicHandler.ashx?Request=1&workOrderId=" + rowid`? The better will be to use `url: "PublicHandler.ashx"` with `postData: {Request: 1, workOrderId: rowid}`.

The next problem is the usage of `$("#tblRequestWorks tr").remove();`. You don't included any HTML code which you use on the page. If you want to destroy the old grid and create a new one on the same place you should use [GridUnload](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods#add_on_grid_methods) instead of `$("#tblRequestWorks tr").remove();`: `$("#tblRequestWorks").jqGrid('GridUnload');` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4233000/315935) and example).

You can also remove `dataType: "json"` from the code. jqGrid don't know the option and you already use the correct `datatype: "json"` option.

I think you can change your code so that the usage of [GridUnload](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods#add_on_grid_methods) will be not needed. Only changing on some parameters of the second grid (`$("#tblRequestWorks")`) and reloading it with respect of `$("#tblRequestWorks").trigger('reloadGrid', [{page: 1}]);` seems me enough.

One more remark: you should be very careful in the `id` values for the second grid. It is not permitted to have id duplicates on the page. If you can't generate unique ids on the server you can consider to use `idPrefix` option of the grid.

Comment: @mohsen: which example you mean? If you create jqGrid once many other dives over the `<table>` element will be created. To delete existing grid it is not enough to delete all `<tr>` elements inside of the `<table>`. The `GridUnload` method do all the work. So you will be able to create another grid on the same place.